# problem with unistd.h in VC++

Tags: visual-c++

It always produce an error that cant find "unistd.h" why? Any remedies for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why? It's just not there. It looks like you try to compile a program that is not portable or you try to port the program to Windows.

`unistd.h` is a not a standard header. Probably you find it only on Unix-like systems.

See: [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unistd.h)

Comment: If the program uses unistd.h, it should compile fine on Linux, the BSDs, and OSX - I would say that's "portable" (also, I would personally call it a "standard header", but I spend a lot of time around POSIX so you may feel differently). The issue is that it's not portable to Windows, which does not provide unistd.h. #ifdef WIN32 to the rescue! :)

Comment: @Matthew Iselin: I don't want to claim a definitiv definition of "portable". But I could give a list of environments that does not include this header too. If you have a "standard header" you need to tell us the "standard". ANSI C might be one, POSIX another. So you can find something more or less "portable". At least the (POSIX) code in question is not portable to "visul-c++" for which this question is tagged.

Answer (score 3):

[Services for Unix](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=896c9688-601b-44f1-81a4-02878ff11778&DisplayLang=en) ships with various linux related headers (including unistd.h), so you could use that.
But that might require to link some of the SFU libraries..

Answer (score 0):

See [Is there a replacement for unistd.h for Windows (Visual C)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341817/is-there-a-replacement-for-unistd-h-for-windows-visual-c) for a partial replacement.  (If you can add aditional functionality, please do so).