# write function requires unistd.h on Unix, what about windows?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, posix, unistd.h

I've changed from a linux computer to a windows and I'm having trouble compiling my code because these two OS don't share the same header files.

Since the unistd.h is not obviously included, Visual C doesn't know what `read()`, `write()`, `close()`, `socklen_t()` and `bzero()`functions are. Can anyone help me with this?

I've googled this: [Is there a replacement for unistd.h for Windows (Visual C)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341817/is-there-a-replacement-for-unistd-h-for-windows-visual-c)

I have no idea how unistd.h works, nor do I know how to code my own. Can someone please link me to one?

Comment: What was wrong with the unistd.h replacement in the accepted answer to the linked question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) to compile the program, which includes (among other things) GCC (and its headers). Try installing that and then compiling your program and see if everything works OK.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Visual C... I've been compiling my code through its debug (F5), how do I change it to Visual C to use MinGW instead?

Comment: @stockoverflow I'm not aware of any way to integrate Visual Studio with MinGW. You compile programs with MinGW like you would in Linux -- from the command line, generally using the same commands.

Comment: Okay cool, command prompt is the same as the terminal on linux right?

Comment: @stockoverflow not really -- some of the commands on Windows are different and many GNU/Linux programs aren't there -- but the commands for compiling with MinGW are the same as those for GCC on Linux. You shouldn't run in to any problems using the Windows command prompt.

Answer (score 11):

`read`, `write` and `close` are in `<io.h>`, just like they traditionally were on Unix.

Offhand, I don't know of a `bzero` being included on Windows at all -- if you care at all about portability, you normally want to use `memset` instead.

`socklen_t` isn't normally used on Windows -- most things that would be `socklen_t` on Unix use either `size_t` or `int` on Windows (`socklen_t` on Unix is currently another reference to the same underlying type as `size_t`, added in case it might be useful someday -- aka, a solution in search of a problem).