# unknown type name 'pid_t' because of using unistd.h

Tags: objective-c, visual-studio, unistd.h

I am getting this error: `unknown type name 'pid_t'`. I think Build is failing due to commenting of a header file: `unistd.h`. Since windows does not support unistd.h, i comment `#include <unistd>` and the only use of this header is `pid_t` so I am looking forward to add pid_t definition manually in Visual Studio based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/826027/1333160).
any help?

Comment: Do you compile on Windows or OS X or both? Do you *need* `pid_t` when you compile on Windows?

Comment: @MartinR just on windows, and yes i need `pid_t` to compile on Windows

Comment: Can you provide more information where `pid_t` is needed? It is some Unix source that you want to compile on Windows? Do you also need `getpid()` ?

Comment: it's a program under UNIX, and i'm trying to compile that on windows. i have corrected every error except this. it has used **pid_t** like this: `pid_t pidVirtuaCard=0;` and `if( (pidVirtuaCard=fork()) < 0 )`. And no i don't need to use `getpid()` anywhere.

Comment: Where is `fork()` defined? That is not a Windows function.

Comment: ow. that's the next problem. Fork() is also defined in <unistd.h> and there is no alternative of this header file for windows :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows does not have a `fork()` function. You have the following options:

- Rewrite the program to use `CreateProcess()`. But note that this is not a 1-to-1 replacement. It creates a new process that, unlike `fork()`, is not a copy of the calling process.
- Use an environment that simulates the Unix API, for example [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com).

Comment: tnx Martin. i should start now!