# Hadoop 2.5.2 mvn build fail Windows 7 x64 - compile-ms-native-dll on hadoop-common?

Tags: java, windows, maven, hadoop, msbuild

I'm following the Hadoop2OnWindows Wiki [here](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows), and I've read the `BUILDING.txt` in the source tree many times. I think I have all the dependencies figured out, but yet I get a weird `Failed to execute goal (compile-ms-native-dll)` error (complete log below).

I have installed Windows SDK 7.1

The following things are in my PATH:

- `Cygwin/bin`
- MSBuild (`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`)
- Protocol Buffer 2.5.0
- Zlib and Zlib/include (so that it has access to zlib.h)
- Findbugs
- Maven

I have also set `Platform=x64`, and needless to say, my `JAVA_HOME` and `M2_HOME` are also set.

I'm running `mvn package -Pdist,native-win,docs -DskipTests -Dtar` in the Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt.

I earlier had `Gnuwin32` which was giving me the below error, but moved to `Cygwin/bin` suspecting something might be amiss with `Gnuwin32`, but I still get the below error. What do I do?

Here's the error log,

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (com
pile-ms-native-dll) on project hadoop-common: Command execution failed. Process
exited with an error: 1(Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (compile-ms-native-dll) on project h
adoop-common: Command execution failed.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThre
adedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution fai
led.
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:208)
        ... 19 more
```

It's only at `hadoop-common` that it's failing. Here are some more logs that might be of use, I'm just not able to figure out what it is though,

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (compile-ms-native-dll) @ hadoop-common --
-
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec from plugi
n realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2, parent: sun.m
isc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1e4ad14c]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec' with bas
ic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) arguments = [C:\hdc\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common/src/main/n
ative/native.sln, /nologo, /p:Configuration=Release, /p:OutDir=C:\hdc\hadoop-com
mon-project\hadoop-common\target/bin/, /p:CustomSnappyPrefix=, /p:CustomSnappyLi
b=, /p:CustomSnappyInclude=, /p:RequireSnappy=false]
[DEBUG]   (f) basedir = C:\hdc\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common
[DEBUG]   (f) classpathScope = runtime
[DEBUG]   (f) executable = msbuild
[DEBUG]   (f) longClasspath = false
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.5.2 @ C:
\hdc\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@1e54fd3d
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Executing command line: msbuild C:\hdc\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-comm
on/src/main/native/native.sln /nologo /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutDir=C:\hdc\
hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target/bin/ /p:CustomSnappyPrefix= /p:Custom
SnappyLib= /p:CustomSnappyInclude= /p:RequireSnappy=false
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 23-11-2014 00:07:43.
Project "C:\hdc\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.sln"
on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Release|x64".
Project "C:\hdc\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.sln"
(1) is building "C:\hdc\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\nati
ve.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Touching "..\..\..\target\native\Release\native.unsuccessfulbuild".
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64\CL.exe /c /I.
.\winutils\include /I..\..\..\target\native\javah /IC:\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\include
/IC:\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\include\win32 /I.\src /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /O2 /Oi /GL /D
WIN32 /D NDEBUG /D _WINDOWS /D _USRDLL /D NATIVE_EXPORTS /D _WINDLL /D _UNICODE
/D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"..\..
\..\target\native\Release\\" /Fd"..\..\..\target\native\Release\vcWindows7.1SDK.
pdb" /Gd /TC /wd4244 /errorReport:queue src\org\apache\hadoop\io\compress\zlib\Z
libCompressor.c src\org\apache\hadoop\io\compress\zlib\ZlibDecompressor.c
  ZlibCompressor.c
c:\hdc\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\src\org\apache\hadoop
\io\compress\zlib\org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_zlib.h(36): fatal error C1083: C
annot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory [C:\hdc\hadoop-comm
on-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.vcxproj]
  ZlibDecompressor.c
c:\hdc\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\src\org\apache\hadoop
\io\compress\zlib\org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_zlib.h(36): fatal error C1083: C
annot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory [C:\hdc\hadoop-comm
on-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\hdc\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\nativ
e\native.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\hdc\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\nativ
e\native.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\hdc\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.sln" (default
 target) (1) ->
"C:\hdc\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.vcxproj" (def
ault target) (2) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  c:\hdc\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\src\org\apache\hado
op\io\compress\zlib\org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_zlib.h(36): fatal error C1083:
 Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory [C:\hdc\hadoop-co
mmon-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.vcxproj]
  c:\hdc\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\src\org\apache\hado
op\io\compress\zlib\org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_zlib.h(36): fatal error C1083:
 Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory [C:\hdc\hadoop-co
mmon-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the log, it is obviously that you miss zlib.h
Did you set the env var ZLIB_HOME to the directory containing zlib.h?
Note that put zlib.h directory in PATH is wrong and not necessary, only zlib bin directory is needed, as said in Building guide https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/branches/branch-2/BUILDING.txt?view=markup

Also, zlib.h requires some header not present in Windows, so you will need to download those headers and put in the same folder with zlib.h. 
For more details, see [Is there a replacement for unistd.h for Windows (Visual C)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341817/is-there-a-replacement-for-unistd-h-for-windows-visual-c) to get unistd.h,
and https://gist.github.com/ashelly/7776712 to get getopt.h

For those folks on Win32 (like me), you may have faced much more troubles. The key solution should be editing .sln and .vcxprj file of winutils and native package so that they are compatible with Win32 platform.

Comment: Turns out `ZLIB_HOME` needs to be added for the headers and then dll needs to be separately added to the path...

Answer (score 0):

I've personally used the command `mvn clean package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true` succesfully for building version 2.4.1 on windows 8. I had lots of different problems, but don't remember this being one of them. But it does seem to complain about zlib.

Comment: Ah, Let me try this. I'll get back to you soon. Thanks for this! :)

Answer (score 0):

Download protobuf and add it to your PATH

https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/detail?name=protoc-2.5.0-win32.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: I've mentioned in my question the various softwares that are in my PATH already. Protobuf is in my PATH already.