# NodeJS - Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h':

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-2012, makefile, node-gyp

I am using `VisualStudio 2012` and run on a `windows 7` machine.

I want to execute the command `make all` under my windows machine. For this I installed [Make for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm).

Furthermore, I want to compile node library [talib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/talib).

I opened the make file to execute the commands by nodeJS itself. That`s the command I want to run:

```
cd ./src/lib && node build.js && cd ../../ && node-gyp configure  && node-gyp build
```

The first part, runs well:

```
cd ./src/lib && node build.js
```

However, running the second part`cd ../../ && node-gyp configure  && node-gyp build`, I get several errors:

```
Kalimini@Kalimini-PC ~/nodeWorkspace/TestProject/node_modules/node-talib-master/sr
c/lib (master)
$ cd ../../ && node-gyp configure  && node-gyp build
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@1.0.2
gyp info using node@0.10.25 | win32 | ia32
gyp info spawn python
gyp info spawn args [ 'c:\\Users\\Kalimini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\n
ode-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-G',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=auto',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'c:\\Users\\Kalimini\\nodeWorkspace\\TestProject\\node_mod
ules\\node-talib-master\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'c:\\Users\\Kalimini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\n
ode-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'c:\\Users\\Kalimini\\.node-gyp\\0.10.25\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=c:\\Users\\Kalimini\\.node-gyp\\0.10.25',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=c:\\Users\\Kalimini\\nodeWorkspace\\CoinA
nalytics\\node_modules\\node-talib-master',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'c:\\Users\\Kalimini\\nodeWorkspace\\TestProject\\node_mod
ules\\node-talib-master\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info ok
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@1.0.2
gyp info using node@0.10.25 | win32 | ia32
gyp info spawn C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=Win32' ]
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  talib.cpp
..\src\talib.cpp(31): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h':
No such file or directory [c:\Users\Kalimini\nodeWorkspace\TestProject\node_mod
ules\node-talib-master\build\talib.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Users\Kalimini\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:
12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Users\\Kalimini\
\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd c:\Users\Kalimini\nodeWorkspace\TestProject\node_modules\node-talib
-master
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.25
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I also tried `node-gyp configure --msvs_version=2012` however, this gives me the same result.

Any recommendation what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**unistd.h** is a UNIX header file, not found by default on windows.

Either replace `unistd.h` with `io.h` for almost the same coverage, or use the GNU windows port found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/157001/Full-getopt-Port-for-Unicode-and-Multibyte-Microso)

Related: [Is there a replacement for unistd.h for Windows (Visual C)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341817/is-there-a-replacement-for-unistd-h-for-windows-visual-c)

Edit: I just compiled the module with `#include <unistd.h>` commented out successfully in file `src/talib.cpp` line 31

Comment: Where would I find the io.h header? Would I be able to rename that to unistd.h whereever npm is looking for it and hope things hold together?