# To enable parallel build, please add the '/m' switch

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, pty, terminal-emulator

I wan to run this sample https://github.com/Gottox/node-webterm , but when i executing the command npm install it shows the error msg.

```
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
  exechelper.cpp
..\src\exechelper.cpp(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.
h': No such file or directory [V:\node-webterm-master\node_modules\child_pty\bu
ild\exechelper.vcxproj]
  pty.cpp
..\src\pty.cpp(25): error C2027: use of undefined type 'winsize' [V:\node-webte
rm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vcxproj]
          ..\src\pty.cpp(22) : see declaration of 'winsize'
..\src\pty.cpp(25): error C2227: left of '->ws_row' must point to class/struct/
union/generic type [V:\node-webterm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vcx
proj]
..\src\pty.cpp(26): error C2027: use of undefined type 'winsize' [V:\node-webte
rm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vcxproj]
          ..\src\pty.cpp(22) : see declaration of 'winsize'
..\src\pty.cpp(26): error C2227: left of '->ws_col' must point to class/struct/
union/generic type [V:\node-webterm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vcx
proj]
..\src\pty.cpp(27): error C2027: use of undefined type 'winsize' [V:\node-webte
rm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vcxproj]
          ..\src\pty.cpp(22) : see declaration of 'winsize'
..\src\pty.cpp(27): error C2227: left of '->ws_xpixel' must point to class/stru
ct/union/generic type [V:\node-webterm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.
vcxproj]
..\src\pty.cpp(27): error C2027: use of undefined type 'winsize' [V:\node-webte
rm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vcxproj]
          ..\src\pty.cpp(22) : see declaration of 'winsize'
..\src\pty.cpp(27): error C2227: left of '->ws_ypixel' must point to class/stru
ct/union/generic type [V:\node-webterm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.
vcxproj]
..\src\pty.cpp(31): error C2027: use of undefined type 'winsize' [V:\node-webte
rm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vcxproj]
          ..\src\pty.cpp(22) : see declaration of 'winsize'
..\src\pty.cpp(31): error C2227: left of '->ws_col' must point to class/struct/
union/generic type [V:\node-webterm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vcx
proj]
..\src\pty.cpp(33): error C2027: use of undefined type 'winsize' [V:\node-webte
rm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vcxproj]
          ..\src\pty.cpp(22) : see declaration of 'winsize'
..\src\pty.cpp(33): error C2227: left of '->ws_row' must point to class/struct/
union/generic type [V:\node-webterm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vcx
proj]
..\src\pty.cpp(39): error C2027: use of undefined type 'winsize' [V:\node-webte
rm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vcxproj]
          ..\src\pty.cpp(22) : see declaration of 'winsize'
..\src\pty.cpp(39): error C2227: left of '->ws_row' must point to class/struct/
union/generic type [V:\node-webterm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vcx
proj]
..\src\pty.cpp(40): error C2027: use of undefined type 'winsize' [V:\node-webte
rm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vcxproj]
          ..\src\pty.cpp(22) : see declaration of 'winsize'
..\src\pty.cpp(40): error C2227: left of '->ws_col' must point to class/struct/
union/generic type [V:\node-webterm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vcx
proj]
..\src\pty.cpp(44): error C2079: 'w' uses undefined struct 'winsize' [V:\node-w
ebterm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vcxproj]
..\src\pty.cpp(46): error C2664: 'makews' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'in
t *' to 'winsize *' [V:\node-webterm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vc
xproj]
          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast,
   C-style cast or function-style cast
..\src\pty.cpp(48): error C2065: 'TIOCSWINSZ' : undeclared identifier [V:\node-
webterm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vcxproj]
..\src\pty.cpp(48): error C3861: 'ioctl': identifier not found [V:\node-webterm
-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vcxproj]
..\src\pty.cpp(50): error C2664: 'applyws' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'i
nt *' to 'winsize *' [V:\node-webterm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.v
cxproj]
          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast,
   C-style cast or function-style cast
..\src\pty.cpp(55): error C2079: 'w' uses undefined struct 'winsize' [V:\node-w
ebterm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vcxproj]
..\src\pty.cpp(59): error C2664: 'makews' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'in
t *' to 'winsize *' [V:\node-webterm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vc
xproj]
          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast,
   C-style cast or function-style cast
..\src\pty.cpp(60): error C3861: 'openpty': identifier not found [V:\node-webte
rm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.vcxproj]
..\src\pty.cpp(64): error C2664: 'applyws' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'i
nt *' to 'winsize *' [V:\node-webterm-master\node_modules\child_pty\build\pty.v
cxproj]
          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast,
   C-style cast or function-style cast
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` fail
ed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (V:\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\node_modul
es\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "V:\\NodeJS\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\
bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd V:\node-webterm-master\node_modules\child_pty
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "V:\\NodeJS\\\\node.exe" "V:\\NodeJS\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-
cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! child_pty@0.5.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the child_pty@0.5.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the child_pty package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls child_pty
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     V:\node-webterm-master\npm-debug.log
```

1. I have installed python 2.7.3, windows 7 SDK as referred from https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation. But still got the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629653/nodejs-cannot-open-include-file-unistd-h

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, my problem was solved when I removed a dependency from the package.json that had a link to the github page instead of the version. switched that dependency from 'https://githubpage' to '0.0.0.' after looking for that dependency on npm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).