# Implementing a custom unistd.h for windows to work on Visual Studio - problems

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, unistd.h

I've inherited source code for a dll file that was originally written for linux. I'm using windows and visual studio and a change to linux is a no can-do, unfortunately. In particular, one of the classes requires unistd.h.

Since windows does not have anything like unistd.h, I tried implementing one in accordance with
[what was nicely written here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341817/is-there-a-replacement-for-unistd-h-for-windows-visual-c).

I created a header file unistd.h and added it to the header files of my project (I also made a custom getopts, in accordance with [this](https://gist.github.com/ashelly/7776712). Unfortunately, this hasn't fixed my problem by much - my code won't build, as I keep getting

`Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory`

My custom unistd.h is among the header files of my solution, so I completely don't understand what's wrong. I've included it using

```
#include "unistd.h"
```

since it is a custom header.

Any suggestions and help will be appreciated. Thank you for the attention.

Comment: It's difficult to see what's wrong with your code, since you've not posted any code. You could at least post the snippet where you're including the header.

Comment: Try `#include "unistd.h"` instead of `#include <unistd.h>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that all your header and source files should be in the same VS project folder - the original header and source files where on my computer in another folder and after creating a new project I used add existing item and found and chose them to add.

The unistd.h file I created later by adding a new item to the project - effectively both file groups where in two different places and that contributed to the fact that they didn't "see" the custom unistd.h. It wasn't a problem with the code or the way I included the header file, but with the placing of the files.