# How does Windows process operands given to a program in C?

Tags: c, windows, getopt

I wonder if there is an equivalent for getopt() in POSIX systems.

Comment: This question is not an exact duplicate of the one linked.

Comment: `getopt` only handles whatever is passed in `argv`, but not putting anything into `argv`.

Comment: I mean to say what function is available in the Windows C standard library to process arguments--such as lol.exe /a /v

Comment: @JeremyP - [But the answer to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/342494/817643) is true to the text above the close layout "**This question already has an answer here**".