# Py ILM Base not compiling on windows

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, openexr

I've downloaded the latest copy from [Latest Open EXR repo](https://github.com/openexr/openexr) and compiled most everything without any problems. However, when I get to PyILMBase it fails.

There are two distinct issues with my attempts:

> Error C2491   'PyImath::FixedArray::name': definition of dllimport function not allowed PyImath (...)\src\pyilmbase-2.2.1\PyImath\PyImath.cpp   41

and an import to unistd.h that kind of gets addressed [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341817/is-there-a-replacement-for-unistd-h-for-windows-visual-c?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

my question being, has anybody successfully compiled this for windows? It seems odd that I can't find any specific info about that compiling error. Am I missing something in the way that C++ works?

This project makes extensive use of whatever it is that causes the error C2491, so going in and changing it would be a little complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IlmBase is compiled as a shared library. A shared library must provide their function declarations in order your program can find them.
It's perform by declaring them as `dllimport` or `dllexport` depending on the situation.

- __declspec(dllimport): imports the implementation from a DLL so your application can use it.
- __declspec(dllexport): tells the linker that you want this object to be made available for other DLL's to import. It is used when creating a DLL that others can link to.

These keywords are generally handled by a single macro. In your case `PYIMATH_EXPORT`.

These lines are from `PyImathTask.h`

```
#if defined(PYIMATH_EXPORTS)                         // create library  
  #define PYIMATH_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)  
#else                                                // use library  
  #define PYIMATH_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)  
#endif
```

So, because you want to make these functions available from your application, you must add `PYIMATH_EXPORTS` as a preprocessor definition.

Actually, PyIMath's properties mispells it - they've write it as `PyImath_EXPORTS` - ... 
To fix that, in vs2015, go to the PyImath's properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Replace `PyImath_EXPORTS` by `PYIMATH_EXPORTS`.

It's probably the same thing for PyIex...