# Metaphone-pt-br library for Windows 10 returns "No such file or directory" error when pip install

Tags: python, installation, pip

I downloaded this [library](https://github.com/carlosjordao/metaphone-ptbr) on github and am trying to install with Python using `pip install .` but the following error message appears:

```
metaphone_ptbrpy.c (32): fatal error C1083
Cannot open include file: '../source/metaphone_ptbr.h'
No such file or directory
 
error: command 'C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\ x86_amd64\\ 
cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

and the file that the error message says does not exist, in fact it does (follow print):

[image]

What do I do?

**#Edit 1**

Print of source folder bellow:
[image]

Comment: In what directory did you run `pip install .`? The error message indicates you need to run it in `python/`. Also, the directory structure looks different from what I see in the repo. All those files in the picture should be in `sources/` not `python/`.

Comment: `pip` runs in a temporary directory so you have to copy `../source/` to that directory in `setup.py`. Having `MANIFEST` is not enough.

Comment: @tatsuki.dev Hello, i'm running the command inside /python folder. I edited my post and added a print to show /source folder and compared to what's in the git repository and they are the same

Comment: @phd Hello, I copied the /source folder into the /python folder but the error message persists when running pip install .

Comment: After copying `../source/` folder into the `python/` edit `setup.py` and remove `..` in both `join()`s.

Comment: …And from `metaphone_ptbrpy.c`.

Comment: @phd I did what you said; setup.py it looked like this: join("source", "metaphone_ptbr.c") and include_dirs=[".", join("source")] while for metaphone_ptbrpy.c it looked like this: #include "/source/metaphone_ptbr.h" but the error message persists

Comment: `#include "/…"` — really from root? ;-)

Comment: @phd you were right hehe now the message error finally changed! Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory; I'm doing some research

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? I believe `unistd.h` is a UNIX-only header. This Stack Overflow question appears to cover how to create an equivalent on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341817/is-there-a-replacement-for-unistd-h-for-windows-visual-c

Comment: @tatsuki.dev Hello, thanks for the tip. I created a file "io.h" following the instructions on the link you sent me, the error changed to "Cannot open include file: 'getopt.h': No such file or directory". I think there is no way, I will have to migrate to a Linux machine

Answer (score 0):

Not sure though Try it with the -e argument. `pip install -e youpackage`

Comment: Hello, I tried what you said but this message appears: "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

I got in touch with the library developer, he helped me a lot. I also applied the suggestions that @phd talked about in the question comments. The complete solution:

1. copy `/source` folder into the `/python` folder
2. edit `/python/setup.py`

change this:

```
c_ext = Extension("metaphoneptbr", ["metaphone_ptbrpy.c", join("..", "source", "metaphone_ptbr.c")])

setup(
    name='Metaphone-ptbr',
    version='1.17',
    ext_modules=[c_ext],
    include_dirs=[".", join("..", "source")]
)
```

for this:

```
c_ext = Extension("metaphoneptbr", ["metaphone_ptbrpy.c", join("source", "metaphone_ptbr.c")])

setup(
    name='Metaphone-ptbr',
    version='1.17',
    ext_modules=[c_ext],
    include_dirs=[".", join("source")]
)
```

3. edit `/python/metaphone_ptbrpy.c`:

change this:

```
#include "../source/metaphone_ptbr.h"
```

for this:

```
#include "source/metaphone_ptbr.h"
```

4. replace the files `/source/metaphone_ptbr.c` and `/source/metaphone_ptbr.h` for [this](https://pastebin.com/s911tDSi) and [this](https://pastebin.com/G4B77RDB)
5. run `python setup.py build` command in `/python` folder to build the project and then run `pip install .` to complete the installation.

to test if everything is okay, just run the command:

```
from metaphoneptbr import phonetic
print(phonetic('hello'))
```

PS: if when executing the command above a warning appears, just change the file `/python/metaphone_ptbrpy.c` for [that](https://pastebin.com/RHxEFSpL) version

- The author said that all these modifications that were necessary to run the Metaphone-ptbr library for Windows 10 will be added to the repository itself, but anyway, I am sharing with you how the solution went step by step.