# #include<unistd.h> error in C (In Visual Studio Code)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, operating-system, unistd.h

[This image is of the code I've entered in VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKVem.png)

[This is the image that shows the error in getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScbqB.png)

I was going through a youtube tutorial to learn about forks in C when I entered the above-mentioned code it gave me this error -

*#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (F:\C\fork.c).C/C++(1696)
cannot open source file "unistd.h"C/C++(1696)*

The code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    fork();
    printf("Hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suppose you are using Windows or DOS. I suppose also that Windows doesn't support unistd.h!

Comment: See this about unistd.h/Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341817/is-there-a-replacement-for-unistd-h-for-windows-visual-c

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Post text as text

Comment: Seel also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985281/what-is-the-closest-thing-windows-has-to-fork